# NumberFormatException from parseDouble()

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

My goal is to take a series of streaming numbers and place it into a multi-dimensional array.  I do realize that this could be done in a non-multi-dimesional array, but my goal is to eventually expand the number of columns. However, I get an error NumberFormatException which I believe is coming from the parseDouble. Could someone explain my error?

Please see code below with LogCat error. Thank you.

Added the log.d("",readMessage,null);

This is a segment of my log.d. Are the blank spots null?

```
04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 0.03
04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 0.

04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 
04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 0.03
04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 0.

04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 
04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 0.03
04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 0.

04-04 21:19:33.196: D/(13272): 



        case MESSAGE_READ:


                for(int a= 0; a <30000; a++)
                {
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Voltage: "+ readMessage);
                    double[] convert = new double[1];
                    for(int z=0; z <1;z++)
                    {
                    convert[z]= Double.parseDouble(readMessage);
                    }
                    for(int j=0; j<1;j++)
                    {
                    stored[a][j]= convert[a];
                    }
                }

            break;
```

LogCat

```
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$2.handleMessage(BluetoothChat.java:305)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-02 21:42:42.516: E/AndroidRuntime(10430):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: That's because [`readMessage` is not a valid double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))... so you'd have to either tell us what `readMessage` is when it fails, or add some temporary logging output to monitor it. This isn't really related to arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readMessage variable should contain text only with numbers, "-" sign or point, so "121" or "13.5" or "-5". If there is a string with other symbol, NumberFormatException occurs. Just see (by Log.d for instance), what is in readMessage variable before parsing

Comment: It does. It contains numbers like 0.02, 0.03, 0.92, 1.92. Etc.

Comment: But You're sure that there are 30000 pieces of message. Maybe the first ones are really double, but after there is no more in buffer, You have null in readMessage and therefore exception occurs?

Comment: Well I'm getting one message at a time, roughly 1000 a second. (It's coming from my arduino microcontroller). How would I fix that?

Comment: @user3385015 Catch the exception, and log the value of `readMessage` that causes it. Then, on a crash, look at the log...

Comment: As Jason C wrote, try to Log current value in catch block or even before parse. I'm pretty sure it will say null.

Comment: @JasonC I updated my question to include log.d.. I'm assuming the blank outputs or the "0." are null?

Comment: @user3385015 "0." is a valid double. The blank spots are blank. Blank strings are not valid doubles, so...